# Create a struct in each iteration

Tags: c++, memory, data-structures, stl

I want to store queues in a queue structure from the `stl` library. For some reasons I have to store a queue in each iteration of my program, but I think that create a new queue over and over again is too expensive.

I only know two ways to do this. The first one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    unsigned int limit, i = 0;
    deque<deque<int> > container;
    cin >> limit;
    for ( ; i < limit; i++ ) {
        deque<int> values;
        //set some values in the values structure.
        setValues(values, i);
        container.push(values);
    }
}
```

the second one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    unsigned int limit, i = 0;
    deque<deque<int> > container;
    deque<int> values;
    cin >> limit;
    for ( ; i < limit; i++ ) {
        //reset the structure, i.e. delete al the previous values.
        reset(values);
        //set some values in the values structure.
        setValues(values, i);
        container.push(values);
    }
}
```

the problem here is that I don't know any function for reset my queue, or maybe I have to do `values=NULL`?

How can I do this in an efficient way?

Thanks! :D

Comment: How about`std::deque::clear()`? As in `values.clear()`.

Comment: Is the best way to do it?

Comment: You should use the first method until you've determined for certain that the program is correct but too slow, and your measurements show that the object construction is a major bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push an empty `deque` in the loop, get a reference to it, and then add items to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    unsigned int limit, i = 0;
    deque<deque<int> > container;
    cin >> limit;
    for ( ; i < limit; i++ ) {
        container.push_back(deque<int>());
        deque<int>& values = container.back();
        //set some values in the values structure.
        setValues(values, i);    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the push_back is not necessary, you can just construct `container` specifying the number of default-constructed elements like this: `deque<deque<int> > container(limit);` (of course *after* acquiring `limit` from `cin`).

Answer (score 2):

You should check in debugger what your compiler is actually doing when you make copies of deque. I have checked in VS2013 and its all move semantics - as expected. This is a test code:

```
std::deque<int> getValues() {
    std::deque<int> res;
    res.push_back(1);
    return res; // deque(_Myt&& _Right) called, also other compilers might use RVO
}

std::deque<int> ff;
std::deque<std::deque<int>> aff;
aff.push_back(getValues()); // void push_back(value_type&& _Val) called
```

at first it looks like a lot of copying, but actually in both problematic places move semantics are used, and only pointers of temporary objects are copied, so its all super fast.

But maybe you are stuct in pre c++11 world? At least this fragment

```
  deque<deque<int> > container; 
                 ^^^
```

gives   such a hint.

Comment: Yes, I'm using an older version of C++, what a good obervation!